# Form action and antiCSRF token

Tags: php, forms, validation

I am a bit confused here.

Firstly, do REGISTRATION forms need an antiCSRF token? Or we only use it for LOGIN forms?

If REGISTRATION forms need it too, then i have the following issue:

I have the **index.php** script where i have a form and then some sort of data validation before inserting them to database.

Its like this:

```
<html>
.....
<body>
  <?php

     if(!empty($_POST))
     {
       //perform all kind of data validation

       //when all validation is done i need to move to the next page (**main.php**)

       header('Location:main.php');

      }

  <form method="POST" action="">
  <input type="hidden" name="hashed_token" value="<?php echo antiCSRFToken(); ?>" />

          //all kind of input (username, email, password,...)

  </form>
```

The antiCSRFToken() is a function that generates a random hash.

In order to prevent possible CSRF attacks i need to "save" the generated hash in a **SESSION** variable {**$_SESSION['hashed_token'] = $_POST['hashed_token']**}and then compare it to the value of the hash in the hidden form input field, after we redirect to **main.php**.

But since the form input stays on the same script (**action=""**) [in order for the validation script to be performed] how can i do this? I cannot send the **$_POST['hashed_token']** over to main.php.

Is it a solution to perform the validation on a script between index.php and main.php? Lets say between.php and redirect to main.php as soon as the validation is done? [index.php | between.php | main.php]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm confused by this question.  You put the token in the form and validate it on post.  What's the problem?

Comment: Just a suggestion for the tokens is to have `$_SESSION['hashed_token']` as an array because it will only accept the last page that was opened that created a token/overwrite the token each time.

Comment: I'd also use a hash for the field name. "hashed_token" can be searched for and the value discovered. Where "randomstring" hides itself a little better. Then you'd have a session variable telling you both the fieldname and the expected value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, neither registration nor login forms need CSRF protection. Neither of them do anything with the logged-in user's personal data or authority. That said, there is no real reason to *not* have CSRF protection as you can write a generic system and apply it to every form on the site (unless you explicitly don't want CSRF protection, such as for search forms).

> In order to prevent possible CSRF attacks i need to "save" the generated hash in a SESSION variable {$_SESSION['hashed_token'] = $_POST['hashed_token']}and then compare it to the value of the hash in the hidden form input field,

This is all sensible

> after we redirect to main.php.

Don't do that. Put the code to do the comparison in a general function. Include it on all the form processing pages and run it when you process the form.

Comment: So, i can generate a hash and compare it in the same script?

Comment: Of course. It's a different request and you're comparing data coming from the user, not data that you *just* created in the same run of the same program

Comment: OK! So on the first request i generate it and save it inside the form, and on the second request compare it?

Comment: In addition, search forms *should not* be using `POST`.

Comment: @christostsang — Yes, although it is better to think of them as "request for form" and "request with form data".